# Request resource is not found 404 error while running maven project on tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

I am running my spring-rest application build on maven on tomcat in eclipse. While running the project on tomcat server it is showing 404 request resource is not found. I imported the rest project from( https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book )[image]

my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


<display-name>roo-spring-data-jpa</display-name>

<description>Roo generated roo-spring-data-jpa application</description>


<!-- Enable escaping of form submission contents -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Handles Spring requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>roo-spring-data-jpa</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>roo-spring-data-jpa</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/uncaughtException</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
</error-page>
```

my ApplicationConfig.java file

```
  package com.oreilly.springdata.rest;

  import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
  import javax.sql.DataSource;

 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import       org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
 import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
 import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
 import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
  import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
  import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
  import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
  import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

  /**
  * Spring JavaConfig configuration class to setup a Spring container   and    infrastructure components like a
* {@link DataSource}, a {@link EntityManagerFactory} and a {@lin PlatformTransactionManager}.
* 
* @author Oliver Gierke
*/
 @Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
 class ApplicationConfig {

/**
 * Bootstraps an in-memory HSQL database.
     * 
 * @return
 * @see http 
 *      ://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database
 *      -support
 */
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
}

/**
 * Sets up a {@link LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean} to use Hibernate. Activates picking up entities from the
 * project's base package.
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
}
```

}

I was struck here for an hour, So i am posting it here. can any one please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: @Jens.Thanks for replay. I imported the project from [  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book  ] . in this i am running rest project. Which file i need to post here.

Comment: @Jens. hey i got same error every time while i run my project can you please help me i had downloaded code form this URL : [ http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/ ] even i run any of the project its gives same error

Answer (score 4):

Try `http://localhost:8080/spring-data-book-reset/index.jsp` if not works
then
Manually copy the `spring-data-book-reset.war` file into `Tomcat/webapps/` and up the server manually in this way --> Go to `Tomcat/bin` in terminal and type `sh catalina.sh run`. Now try using your url. It might works.
If it not works, somtimes it may be your configuration problem. Then post your `web.xml` and `ApplicationContextConfiguration.xml` here.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I just imported the code from git. you can check my code at ( https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book ). i am imported rest project from above link. sorry for late response.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common problem. Follow the steps:

- Click on Window > Show view > Server OR right click on the server in
  "Servers" view, select "Properties".
- Open the Overview screen for the server by double clicking it. In the
  Server locations tab , select "Use Tomcat location".
- Save the configurations and restart the Server.

That's it...!!

Comment: thanks for replay.  Currently in Server location tab is is set as "use work space meta data"  i am unable to change it to the "Use tomcat installation" .  when i click on "Use tomcat installation" it is not selecting that.

Comment: Delete the server configuration in eclipse and add a new server. Then you'll be able to edit.

Comment: Then, you need to add a new server.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons for this issue.

1. The war deployed does not correspond to the same name as requested
2. As you are using spring, there might not be any confirguration xml used as servlet in the web.xml
3. You might not have defined any welcome page.

please share your web.xml and folder structure for better understanding

Comment: Thanks for replay. As it is a spring-rest-jpa application i do not have any web.xml file. You can check my imported project here. ( https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book/tree/master/rest  )

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your build path entries are being exported to Tomcat. Check the entries in Web Deployment Assembly under your project properties.

Hope this helps